# Sound card not detected on LTS 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, but I have used it for a while, more than 2 months.
A couple of weeks ago I did an update.
After that I have not been able to get the sound card detected.
I have tried a mass of different solutions to no avail, I even upgraded to the latest BIOS firmware and did nothing.
A very similar problem is the one found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218772/ubuntu-20-04-missing-soundcard)

I have an Elitebook 850 G6

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
```

Kernel:

```
uname -r
5.3.0-42-generic
```

Proc - /dev/snd also show as if there is not sound card:

```
echo "~PROC~";cat /proc/asound/cards;echo "~SND~"; ls -l /dev/snd
~PROC~
--- no soundcards ---
~SND~
total 0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 mar 21 15:54 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 mar 21 15:54 timer
```

I have tried removing alsa things, adding them back, a lot of stuff that I could find on the internet, none of which has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am actually thinking on giving up on Ubuntu if I cannot find a solution here. Pitty really, cause it has worked well so far.

Please also keep in mind that it used to work before the upgrade I did.

Thanks in advance for any help (and stay safe)