# Sound card not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, sound, 20.04, 19.04

The sound on my ThinkPad Yoga X1 used to work a while ago. I'm not sure what changed, but now it doesn't work anymore. It <strike>still works</strike> continued to work for some time on the parallel installation of ubuntu 18.04 (yes, I have the same distro installed twice). It does still work on the parallel installation of windows 10.

When I press the volume buttons on my keyboard, it changes the volume of a "Dummy Output" device.

`lspci`  lists the audio device:

```bsh
$ lspci | grep -A8 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 11)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM (rev 11)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 2263 (rev 03)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
```

But aplay does not find it

```bsh
sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for generic: 
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

```bsh
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 46332 /  71% / -9.04 dB,   front-right: 46332 /  71% / -9.04 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 14
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with ZFS on root. That means I can try a solution and roll back if it did not work. Which means I tried several solutions.

Related links that did not help:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 soundcard not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123373/ubuntu-18-04-soundcard-not-detected?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Sound card not detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting)
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html?m=1
- https://askubuntu.com/a/815516/606260
- [No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218398/no-sound-dummy-output-error-ubuntu-19-10)
- [Sound card not detected on LTS 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219037/sound-card-not-detected-on-lts-18-04)
- [No sound (dummy output) Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218229/no-sound-dummy-output-ubuntu-19-10)
- [No sound on Ubuntu 19.10. Dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225532/no-sound-on-ubuntu-19-10-dummy-output)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1027405/606260
- https://askubuntu.com/a/811461/606260

What I tried:

- `sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils && reboot`
- `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui`
- adding the user `generic` to the group `audio`
- the three above combined
- a [variation of the above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027405/606260)
- both fixes in the [linuxuprising post](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html?m=1)
- `modprobe snd_hda_intel && modprobe sof_pci_dev`
- Adding `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to the GRUB boot arguments
- Installing a collection of packages from `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/811461/606260)
- Reinstalling alsa-related packages, using dkms. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/632676/606260)
- Reinstalling `pavucontrol` and `pulseaudio` as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087947/606260) QA

My system is

```bsh
$ uname -r
5.3.0-51-generic
```

Possibly unrelated, possibly related:
My screen brightness controls have disappeared as well. They were broken once before, and I fixed that by adding `acpi_backlight=video` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and updating grub and rebooting. But that fix is still in place and still it is broken again.

How can I get the sound working again?

When I boot off a live stick of ubuntu 18.04, the sound does work again.

```bsh
# live system version:
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-28-generic #30-18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# aplay output on live system:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

(On the non-live system)[`/var/log/apt/term.log`](https://askubuntu.com/a/425811/606260) and [`/var/log/apt/history.log`](https://serverfault.com/a/175584/241793) and [`/var/log/dpkg.log`](https://askubuntu.com/a/425884/606260) are all empty when viewed with `sudo vim <filepath>`. But there is a file `history.log.1.gz` which contains all the history. I'm reviewing it, but I don't know what to look out for.

I have booted off the oldest zfs snapshot I currently have on the laptop (not incredibly old, due to me getting complications with zfs back then) and the sound does not work there either. It also does not work when I boot with the older kernel version `5.3.0-28` that is the same as on the live usb stick.

`git diff --no-index apt_live.txt apt_tank.txt` where the files contain the respective outputs of `apt list --installed` gives me too much output. Many version numbers have changed.

---

I have added the tags <kbd>19.04</kbd> and <kbd>20.04</kbd> in retrospect since the fix applies to those as well, according to the sources.

Comment: You didn't tell us what make/model sound card you have. Does the manufacturer make a Linux driver for the device?  You also say you want to get it working *again*. What's changed since it last worked?

Comment: @Nmath I don't know what changed. I wanted to state now that it is still working on the parallel installation which is also Ubuntu 18.04, but it has in the meantime also stopped working there (I have verified again just now). On the Windows system that is also installed in parallel, it is working and shown as "Speakers (Realtek(R) audio"

Comment: What would be a good way to get the information about the manufacturer that would help you answering? The device manager on Windows shows "Intel(R) Display Audio", "Intel Smart Sound Technology (Intel SST)" and "Realtek (R) Audio". The Settings on ubuntu only show the "Dummy Output" and `lspci` on ubuntu is pasted in my question

Comment: I have found [this site](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201906-27127) on the hardware details. It lists " 
Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (8086:9dc8)" and "Intel Unknown"

Comment: Try to figure out what changed. Check your apt logs to see if there were recent updates in any way related to sound. Also check to see when was the last kernel update. Do you keep your system updated?  You could also boot from a liveUSB to make sure the device works on Ubuntu and you can also use that to compare working configs with your installed system.

Comment: @Nmath thank you for your advice. The easiest to check first: it works on my live usb that I had lying around. It has a slightly older kernel version, so it isn't the exact same release though

Comment: In some case, windows "fast boot" can cause such problem: disable it in Windows power options

Comment: @laugeo thank you, but "fast boot" has been disabled since before I installed ubuntu in parallel. I just verified: it's still off

Comment: @Nmath thank you for your help. I have found a solution now. It seems to have been a kernel bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt was [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246476/606260) which fixed the sound but breaks the brightness controls.

I later noticed weird behaviour in combination with my different grub bootloader menus and started to write a new question. While writing that question, I performed more testing until it became more of a blog post than a question, since it also contains several answers to implicit questions.

You will find it below the horizontal line.

#### TL;DR

**Removing `nomodeset` and `acpi_backlight=video`** did the trick for me. Sound and Brightness Controls now work - **possibly at the expense of hibernation.**

> Many open source drivers have removed support for non-kernel mode setting, so in those cases when you use nomodeset you will end up falling back to the very basic VESA un-accelerated driver. This is very much a performance and feature hit.
>   [Source QA](https://askubuntu.com/a/249579/606260)

---

#### Long Writeup of Testing this

This is a new perspective on the question originally posed as [Sound card not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245587/sound-card-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04). It has become wildly more weird. But for you to understand my utter confusion, you'll need some pretext:

I have three partitions with ubuntu 18.04 on each. In the end, I will get rid of two of them, but they are `EXT 4`, `ZFS unencrypted`, `ZFS encrypted`. Each has a different background so that I know to which I am logged in.

I also have grub installed at two places. Probably because I did not set a separate boot partition for the EXT4 system. So I have `/dev/nvme0n1p8/boot` but also `/dev/nvme0n1p5 (boot partition)`. Both contain a kernel and initrd `5.3.0-51-generic`. The `p5` contains also `5.3.0-53-generic` and the `p8/boot` contains also `53.0-28-generic` and some old `4-15-0-101-generic`. However, I'm not even sure these boot partitions matter much.
In order to distinguish the two grubs, I have added a theme to the one on `p5`.

When I start the laptop, it boots to the grub GUI on `p5`. It has some problems with correctly listing multiple zfs partitions so I made a custom entry, but that shouldn't matter here either.
To open the grub GUI on `p8`, I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to the grub terminal and there I enter

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)
```

**When I boot from grub on `p5`, the brightness keys and the sound are broken.

When I boot from grub on `p8`, they work flawlessly.**
I've made sure to use the same kernel and system in both instances. In fact, I have tried several times in the hopes that it may be due to some kernel boot argument.

The problem is not bound to one of the three ubuntu installations. I can boot any of them so that the sound works and so that it does not, depending on the grub I'm using.

The problem is not bound to one kernel version. I can boot from both `51` and `53` into any partition and the sound works or does not, depending on the grub I'm using.

The problem is not due to different kernel images of the same version. I can boot from the `p8` grub with the kernel `53` located on the `p5` partition and the sound will work.

#### Testing

Let us only consider only the simple ext4 partition for now. The encrypted zfs partition behaves the same though (and the unencrypted zfs partition I haven't checked).

First of all, I have tried several combinations of boot arguments, but I think the following three tests should be enough for this question.
[image: table image]

- The first column ("entry") is either `old` for the ext4-menuentry with grub on `p8` or `new1` for the ext4-menuentry with grub on `p5`.
- The `kernel partition` was set to `8` by editing the menuentry to contain `set root=(hd0,gpt8)` right before the line starting with `linux` and prefixing the path to the kernel and to the initrd with `/boot`.
  Analogously, the `kernel partition` was set to `5` by inserting `set root=(hd0,gpt5)` and removing the prefix `/boot` from the kernel and initrd paths.
- Any column between (exclusive) `]kernel version, sound works?[` is about the presence of the respective kernel boot argument. Those are arguments that were set in at least one of the grub menuentries, but as you can see in the table, the behaviour remained the same without those.

I have also tested whether the presence of `quiet splash` has any effect, but it also does not seem to have any.

To be absolutely certain that the boot arguments don't have any impact, I tried booting from the grub terminal directly.

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
boot
```

Sound and brightness keys work in this way.

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
boot
```

Sound and brightness keys do also work in this way! (unexpected at this point)

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
normal
# select menuentry and press E to edit it so that it looks as follows:
setparams 'Ubuntu'
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
# CTRL+X to boot that
```

Sound and brightness keys do also work in this way. (expected since started from grub on `p8`).

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/grub
normal
# select menuentry and press E to edit it so that it looks as follows:
setparams 'Ubuntu'
set root=(hd0,gpt5)
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
# CTRL+X to boot that
```

Sound and brightness keys *still* work in this way! (unexpected!).
Now if I instead don't open the grub terminal and directly go editing the entry, the same behaviour. So there is not some magic involved with the `normal` command.
Also, not writing the `set root=(hd0,gpt5)` seems to be fine.

When I run the entry as it was generated in the grub GUI on `p5`, the brightness and sound do not work. So I shall now try and build that entry from the ground up. (Prepare for lots of typing)

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Sound and brightness keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Sound and brightness keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Boots into emergency mode with "Failed to mount /boot/efi" (wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2 ...)

So I remove the `gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode` again and continue:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Sound and brightness keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Sound and brightness keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

I have inserted the `gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode` again and it still boots well and the Sound and Brightness Keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8 ro nomodeset
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

And the screen brightness and Sound no longer work!

Again, without `nomodeset`:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8 ro
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

The Sound and Brightness keys still work.

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8 ro acpi_backlight=video
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

Sound and Brightness keys still work.
Worth noting that I only had `acpi_backlight=video` there in the first place because the [brightness keys were not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts#comment2083875_1035527). And I had `nomodeset`(which currently seems to be the culprit) there because [it fixes hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218547/606260). Maybe `nomodeset` broke my brightness keys and sound, which I then tried to fix using `acpi_backlight=video`?

So including `nomodeset` again:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8 ro nomodeset acpi_backlight=video
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

The sound and brightness are now **not working**, so it is unclear to me why the brightness fix with `acpi_backlight=video` worked for me last time. I applied it May 9 and the `nomodeset` was already in March... perhaps I removed and re-added that some time and didn't realize the effects it had on the brightness keys.

I would prefer having one problem over having two problems, so here's again removing `nomodeset acpi_backlight=video` and adding the final argument:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu'
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 81e29369-ff69-4424-858c-3489283588d7
fi
linux /vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p8 ro resume=UUID=1ba104f0-35be-42f7-bf71-65e43f6fbcc3
initrd /initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
```

As expected, sound and brightness work again. I have not tested hibernation now. I assume it will either work due to the recent bios and firmware update by lenovo, or still not work in the same way as in my question about it. But that will be a different problem for a different day.

Now for the question that remains: why did it seem like it worked in the old bootloader?
Well... turns out that in most of my tests did not modify "nomodeset". But in one that you can see in the table higher above, the sound did not work with the `p5` bootloader, kernel 51 from `p8`, without `acpi_backlight` and without `nomodeset`.
I can no longer reproduce that. Perhaps I made a mistake while taking notes.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer fixes the sound but breaks the brightness control.**
I am leaving it here for documentation purposes <strike>and hopefully will be able to review it later when I found a better fix.</strike>

**Please consider [this followup answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1247850/606260)!**

---

> [Edit: March 2020] There's a kernel regression (in **Linux 5.3.0-41 and
>   probably newer** versions running on Ubuntu 19.10) which causes a new
>   "dummy output" issue on Ubuntu 19.10.
>
> [...]
>
> There's a regression (thanks JustNiz for notifying me) in the 5.3.0-41
>   and -42 kernel that causes a new "dummy output" issue on **Ubuntu 19.10
>   and 18.04**. The explanations for this bug are available in [this bug
>   report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061), so I won't go into details, and I'll directly tell you how to
>   fix it.
>
> [[Edit] It appears this may also happen for some **Ubuntu 20.04** users.
>
> [Source: linuxuprising](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html?m=1)

> ```bsh
> sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
> ```
>
> Add the following line to
>   the end of this file:
>
> ```
> options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
> ```
>
> Save and close the file **and reboot**
>   your system. You should have the audio back.
>
> [Source: itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

I had already tried that before without success. It has now worked the second time after I not only did the above but also followed [Adam](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/#comments/334121)'s advice to **run `pulseaudio --start` after rebooting**.
Note that this may take a few seconds until the sound starts working.

Because it could have been that only Adam's advice was important, I removed the line `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` again and rebooted. It stopped working again. So I edited it in again and rebooted another time. And this time the sound worked without needing to run `pulseaudio --start`.

I don't understand that, but this seems to be the fix. If it turns out that I need to run `pulseaudio --start` every time at startup, I will just add that command to my `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Although after rebooting a few times to test this, I'm pretty sure you don't actually need the `pulseaudio --start` - just wait some time after the boot. Approximately a minute.

---

Regarding the "possibly related" part of my question

> My screen brightness controls have disappeared as well. They were
>   broken once before, and I fixed that by adding acpi_backlight=video to
>   the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub and updating grub
>   and rebooting. But that fix is still in place and still it is broken
>   again.

Directly after I noticed that the volume keys are now working and making a sound, I pressed a brightness key. And they no longer work. I will try [the fix](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) that was linked to in one of my quoted articles in this answer and edit my answer once I know whether it worked.

---

Regarding the delay after boot until the sound works:
Perhaps this has to do with it.

```bsh
$ dmesg[   44.945151] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   45.576833] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   84.861079] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
[   84.885411] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC285: line_outs=2 (0x14/0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   84.885414] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   84.885416] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   84.885418] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   84.885419] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   84.885421] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[   84.933958] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[   84.934160] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
[   84.934845] input: HDA Intel PCH Headset Jack as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
[   84.934904] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input26
[   84.934952] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
```

Comment: for whom it may concern, the same fix also works for the same issue when updating from 18.04 to 20.04.